# Use of casting to interface type

Tags: java, interface, casting

```
interface I {
    int element = 10;
}
class A implements I
{
    int element = 2;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.element);
        I i = (I)a;
        System.out.println(a.element + " " + i.element);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2

2 10
```

Even after I cast object of type `A` to `I` the value of `element` in `I` doesn't change.

If `I` is a class and `A extends I` then I can change the value of `element in A` and cast it to `I` such that `i.element` has modified value (in this case `A` does not have `element` member)

So does the concept of casting exist in such cases? (class object cast to interface type)

Comment: When you implement methods, you @Override them in the class. Overriding cannot be applied to fields.

Answer (score 4):

> Even after I cast object of type A to I the value of element in I doesn't change.

```
I i = (I)a;
```

That line shows that the instance of a pointing to the type `I`. Which means, you are accessing the variables from type `I` and telling that execute the methods from class `a`.

Polymorphism strictly for methods. There is no polymorphism on variables.

Here is the example :

```
public interface TestInterface {

    int testvarInterface = 0;

}


public class TestParent {

    int testvarFromParent = 0;

}



    public class TestClass extends TestParent implements TestInterface {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TestClass s = new TestClass();
            System.out.println(s.testvarInterface);
            TestInterface in = (TestInterface) s;
            in.testvarInterface = 15; // ERROR: The final field
                                        // TestInterface.testvar
            // cannot be
            // assigned
            System.out.println(s.testvarFromParent); // Points to LHS
            TestParent parent = (TestParent) s;
            parent.testvarFromParent = 20;
            System.out.println(parent.testvarFromParent);

        }

    }
```

After all you have to remember that the variables points to LHS (*naive, bit still*), where as in your interface case, since it is public and `static final` you cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overwrite the value of I.element in implementing classes because variables defined in interfaces are static final. Being static they are not instance variables. And being final they cannot be overwritten.

So A.element is hiding I.element when you are working with a reference of type A. But not when you cast the A instance to its interface type I.